# Shares struct's to multiple packages

Tags: go

This is my first real attempt and playing with GoLang

In my project, I will be contacting multiple carriers to get their "estimate". I have carriera at the moment, but there will be carrierb etc too.

As I will be wanting to use the same struct from the package "estimate", I decided that I should share the struct in one file, rather than passing the variable etc

I feel like I may have over-complicated this already but was hoping I could get some feedback before I keep going?

Everything is working fine at the moment, posting, etc. I've been developing in PHP for 10 years now, so learning a new language is a tad different for me (better late than never)

Thanks in advance!

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
    "xxx/consignments/pkg/carriers"
    "xxx/consignments/pkg/estimate"
)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Initalised main package")
}
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    carrierClient, err := carriers.InitCarriers()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    h := estimate.Handler{
        Carriers: carrierClient,
    }
    router.HandleFunc("/estimate", h.GetEstimate).Methods("POST")
    http.ListenAndServe(":1001", router)
}
```

**xxx/consignments/pkg/types/estimate.go**

```golang
package types

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
)

type EstimateMetrics struct {
    Item []Item `json:"item"`
}
type Item struct {
    Quantity int `json:"qty" validate:"required"`
    Length   int `json:"length" validate:"required"`
    Width    int `json:"width" validate:"required"`
    Height   int `json:"height" validate:"required"`
    Weight   int `json:"weight" validate:"required"`
}

var metrics EstimateMetrics

//Return the Estimate Metrics struct
func EstimateReturn() EstimateMetrics {
    return metrics
}

//Convert the JSON into the struct
func ParseData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //  var metrics EstimateMetrics
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&metrics)
    if err != nil {
        ErrorResponse(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, "Invalid JSON", w)
        return
    }
}
func ErrorResponse(statusCode int, error string, writer http.ResponseWriter) {
    //Create a new map and fill it
    fields := make(map[string]interface{})
    fields["status"] = "error"
    fields["message"] = error
    message, err := json.Marshal(fields)

    if err != nil {
        //An error occurred processing the json
        writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        writer.Write([]byte("An error occured internally"))
    }

    //Send header, status code and output to writer
    writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    writer.WriteHeader(statusCode)
    writer.Write(message)
}
```

**xxx/consignments/pkg/estimate/estimate.go**

```golang
package estimate

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v10"
    "net/http"
    "xxx/consignments/pkg/carriers"
    "xxx/consignments/pkg/types"
)

type Handler struct {
    Carriers *carriers.Carriers
}

//Define the structure of the config file
type EstimateCarriers struct {
    Pricing []struct {
        Name string `yaml:"Name"`
        URL  string `yaml:"URL"`
    } `yaml:"Pricing"`
}

func (h *Handler) GetEstimate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("Reached the estimate function:\n\n")

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    types.ParseData(w, r)
    metrics := types.EstimateReturn()
    //Do some validation for the decoded data
    validate := validator.New()
    for _, v := range metrics.Item {
        validate_error := validate.Struct(v)
        if validate_error != nil {
            for _, e := range validate_error.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
                fmt.Println("Missing Field: " + e.Field())
            }
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("L: %v | W: %v | H: %v\n", v.Length, v.Width, v.Height)
    }

    carrier := h.Carriers
    v := carrier.Carriera
    v.GetEstimate()
    //Go and get the estimates
}

func ErrorResponse(statusCode int, error string, writer http.ResponseWriter) {
    //Create a new map and fill it
    fields := make(map[string]interface{})
    fields["status"] = "error"
    fields["message"] = error
    message, err := json.Marshal(fields)

    if err != nil {
        //An error occurred processing the json
        writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        writer.Write([]byte("An error occured internally"))
    }

    //Send header, status code and output to writer
    writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    writer.WriteHeader(statusCode)
    writer.Write(message)
}
```

**xxx/consignments/pkg/carriers/carriera/carriera.go**

```golang
package carriera

import (
    "fmt"
    "xxx/consignments/pkg/types"
)

type ServerConfig struct {
    URL string `yaml:"URL"`
}

type Carrier struct {
    Config ServerConfig
}
type EstimateStruct struct {
    FromSuburb   string `json:"fromSuburb"`
    FromPostcode int    `json:"fromPostcode"`
    ToSuburb     string `json:"toSuburb"`
    ToPostcode   string `json:"toPostcode"`
    Items        []Item `json:"item"`
}
type Item struct {
    Quantity int `json:"quantity" validate:"required"`
    Length   int `json:"length" validate:"required"`
    Width    int `json:"width" validate:"required"`
    Height   int `json:"height" validate:"required"`
    Weight   int `json:"phsyicalWeeight" validate:"required"`
}

func (c *Carrier) GetEstimate() string {
    metrics := types.EstimateReturn()
    fmt.Println(c.Config.URL)
    fmt.Println(metrics)
    return "hello"
}

func New(config ServerConfig) *Carrier {
    return &Carrier{
        Config: config,
    }
}
```

**consignments/pkg/carriers/carriers.go**

````golang
package carriers

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
    "xxx/consignments/pkg/carriers/carriera"
)

var (
    configFile = "carriers.yml"
)

func InitCarriers() (*Carriers, error) {
    //Read the yaml file to get the configuration addresses
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(configFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //Get all of the carriers configs
    config := &CarrierConfig{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(data, &config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //Return a list of the carrier types
    return &Carriers{
        Carriera: carriera.New(config.Carriera),
    }, nil

}

type Carriers struct {
    Carriera CarrierClient
}

type CarrierConfig struct {
    Carriera carriera.ServerConfig `yaml:"Carriera"`
}

type CarrierClient interface {
    GetEstimate() string
}

```
````

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? What is a carrier? What is it estimating?